# Serve HTTPS traffic on NGINX servers

Tags: nginx, ansible, nginx-config

I'm trying to configure an `Ansible` `NGINX` deploy job to enable `HTTPS` on `NGINX` servers.

I can see that `nginx.conf.je` has `http{...}`. Do I need something similar for `HTTPS` or how is this configured?

Comment: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Comment: Thanks Zeitounator. I literally just came across that page.

Comment: I suggest your read [How much effort is expected from SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/9401096).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to configure it as follows on nginx.conf file -

```
events {}

http {

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.example.com;
        ssl_certificate www.exaple.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
        location / {
            return 200 "Nginx is running";
        }
    }
}
```

Found this at nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html.

Comment: This does not answer the question (being roughly "how and where do I enable and configure https in nginx configuration?").

Comment: Answer doesn't handle HTTPS topic, although "enable HTTPS on NGINX servers" in original post.